# How would I ask "how <adjective> is something?"

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, interrogative

I thought of this while trying to mentally translate "How bad is the sauce?" but this applies to anything. Basically just trying to inquire about the extent of a quality.

> I ordered the car green, but it came blue.
>
> > How blue?

---

> The weather is lovely.
>
> > How lovely?

---

> How bad is the sauce?

---

> How far did he run? (This was previously explained to me as *À quelle distance...* but that doesn't apply to the others and I just wanted to bring it up again. "À quelle distance est-ce qu'il a couru?" Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spoken French, *comment* is often used to translate "how" :

> How blue? → *bleu comment ?*
>
> *Le temps est très beau ! Très beau comment ? / C'est à dire ?*
>
> How bad is the sauce? → *Elle est mauvaise comment, la sauce ?*
>
> How far did he run? → *Il a couru jusqu'où ? / Jusqu'où a-t-il couru ?*

Answer (score 3):

All of those can be: [Jusqu']

à quel point le temps est beau? Oh, très beau!

à quel point la sauce était mauvaise? Elle était franchement dégueulasse.

à quel point bleu? [though it sounds a bit silly]...Oh, bleu très foncé

except: 
Jusqu'où a-t-il ou est-ce qu'il a couru? 
Because how far is not like the other questions.
The others are about the intensity of the a quality/condition....